# Find rotation to make it look at a point in 3D space

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, rotations, angle

I found a function that gets the rotation needed to make something look at a point. I don’t know how it works, though.

But, I do know how it would work in 2D. It would take arctangent of the point’s tangent, and then give me the angle in radians. However, I can’t figure it out in 3D space.

Can someone just give me some help to get me going in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn’t clear. The function was online, so I couldn’t see what the math was.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{o}$ be the camera or observer, and $\vec{t}$ the target.

Furthermore, let $\vec{r}$ be a "right" direction vector.  That is, when viewed from $\vec{o}$, point $\vec{t}+\vec{r}$ is directly right from $\vec{t}$. This sets the rotation of the view from $\vec{o}$ towards $\vec{t}$.

First, we define the unit direction vector from $\vec{o}$ to $\vec{t}$, $\hat{w}$:
$$\hat{w} = \frac{\vec{t} - \vec{o}}{\left\lVert \vec{t} - \vec{o} \right\rVert} \tag{1a}\label{G1a}$$
Next, we use one step of the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthonormalize the right direction vector with respect to $\hat{w}$, giving us a new unit direction vector $\hat{u}$ corresponding to "right".  (Essentially, we remove the part of $\vec{r}$ that is along $\hat{w}$, and normalize the result to unit length, so that the resulting $\hat{u}$ will be perpendicular to $\hat{w}$.)
$$\hat{u} = \frac{\vec{u}}{\lVert\vec{u}\rVert}, \quad \vec{u} = \vec{r} - \hat{w} \left( \hat{w} \cdot \vec{r} \right) \tag{1b}\label{G1b}$$
The third unit vector is perpendicular to both $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{w}$, and in a right-handed coordinate system is
$$\hat{v} = \hat{w} \times \hat{u} \tag{1c}\label{G1c}$$
The rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ to rotate direction $(0,0,1)$ towards $\vec{t} - \vec{o}$; or in other words, the rotation matrix around $\vec{o}$, is
$$\mathbf{R} = \left[\begin{matrix} \hat{u} & \hat{v} & \hat{w} \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} u_x & v_x & w_x \\ u_y & v_y & w_y \\ u_z & v_z & w_z \end{matrix}\right] \tag{1d}\label{G1d}$$

---

In computer graphics, we typically want to do the opposite: we want to rotate and translate the view so that $\vec{o}$ is at origin, $\vec{t}$ is along the positive $z$ axis, and $\vec{t}+\vec{r}$ is on the positive $x$ axis.

To do this, we need the inverse rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$.  However, because $\mathbf{R}$ is orthonormal (all its row vectors perpendicular to each other with length $1$, and all its column vectors perpendicular to each other with length $1$), its inverse is its transpose:
$$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T}$$
and the transform needed to transform point $\vec{p} = (x, y, z)$ thus to $\vec{p}^\prime = (x^\prime, y^\prime, z^\prime)$ is
$$\vec{p}^\prime = \mathbf{R}^{-1} \left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) = \mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{p} - \mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{o} \tag{2a}\label{G2a}$$
ie.
$$\left[\begin{matrix} x^\prime \\ y^\prime \\ z^\prime \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \\ v_x & v_y & v_z \\ w_x & w_y & w_z \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} x - o_x \\ y - o_y \\ z - o_z \end{matrix}\right] \tag{2b}\label{G2b}$$

---

If we extract the constant part from the rotation as the translation vector $\vec{T}$,
$$\vec{T} = -\mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{o} \tag{3a}\label{G3a}$$
we can write the entire transform as
$$\vec{p}^\prime = \mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{p} + \vec{T} \tag{3b}\label{G3b}$$
Using homogenous coordinates, this can be implemented as a single matrix-vector multiplication:
$$\left[\begin{matrix} x^\prime \\ y^\prime \\ z^\prime \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} u_x & u_y & u_z & T_x \\ v_x & v_y & v_z & T_y \\ w_x & w_y & w_z & T_z \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right] \tag{3c}\label{G3c}$$
This is very often used in computer graphics.  Because the fourth component of these vectors is always $1$, only three components per homogenous vector need be stored – and those three match the standard Cartesian coordinate components.  Similarly, usually only the $12$ components on the first three rows of transformation matrices are stored, because the fourth row is always constant.

Note that in terms of elementary operations needed – additions, subtractions, multiplications and divisions – $\eqref{G2a}$ is identical to $\eqref{G3a}$ and $\eqref{G3c}$.

For perspective projection, an additional division per Cartesian coordinate is needed, so that the not-stored fourth component will still be $1$. This is where the name "homogenous" comes from.

Comment: Do note that friends don't let friends use Euler or Tait-Bryan angles for 3D rotation.  Use matrices (and versors or bivectors); they're unambiguous, robust, simple to use (you just need to "grok" the concepts first), and do not have traps or gotchas like rotation order and gimball lock that Euler/Tait-Bryan angles suffer from.